# How to include multiple columns in a select case statement

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a select case statement that I use in a combobox. Please refer below for code. However in the example provided I am only able to use one column at a time I have tried a couple of things examples. End result would be if "current month" is selected use columns "C" and "S".

Attempt 1:

```
nExtend = 1 'Set this as a default.
Select Case MonthComboBox.value
    **Case "Current Month"
        iCol = "C"
    Case "Current Month"
        iCol = "S"**
    Case "Current Month +1"
        iCol = "N"
        nExtend = 5
    Case "Current Month +2"
        iCol = "O"
        nExtend = 4
    Case "Current Month +3"
        iCol = "P"
        nExtend = 3
    Case "Current Month +4"
        iCol = "Q"
        nExtend = 2
End Select
```

Attempt 2:

```
nExtend = 1 'Set this as a default.
Select Case MonthComboBox.value
    ****Case "Current Month"
        iCol = "C" & "S"**
    Case "Current Month +1"
        iCol = "N"
        nExtend = 5
    Case "Current Month +2"
        iCol = "O"
        nExtend = 4
    Case "Current Month +3"
        iCol = "P"
        nExtend = 3
    Case "Current Month +4"
        iCol = "Q"
        nExtend = 2
End Select
```

Actual Code:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()


    Dim irow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim iCol As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim value As Long
    Dim NewPart As Boolean
    Dim ws_warehouse(7) As Worksheet    '7 is total warehouse tab you have
    Dim nExtend As Integer
    Dim cel As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Main")

    Set ws_warehouse(1) = Worksheets("Elkhart East")
    Set ws_warehouse(2) = Worksheets("Tennessee")
    Set ws_warehouse(3) = Worksheets("Alabama")
    Set ws_warehouse(4) = Worksheets("North Carolina")
    Set ws_warehouse(5) = Worksheets("Pennsylvania")
    Set ws_warehouse(6) = Worksheets("Texas")
    Set ws_warehouse(7) = Worksheets("West Coast")

    Set c = ws.Range("A7:A1048576").Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If c Is Nothing Then
    'find first empty row in database
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        irow = lastRow + 1
        NewPart = True
    Else
    'find row where the part is
        irow = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        NewPart = False
    End If

    'check for a part number
    If Trim(Me.PartTextBox.value) = "" Then
      Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Part Number"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.MonthComboBox.value) = "" Then
      Me.MonthComboBox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Month"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.AddTextBox.value) = "" Then
      Me.AddTextBox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Value To Add Or Substract"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    nExtend = 1 'Set this as a default.
    Select Case MonthComboBox.value
        Case "Current Month"
            iCol = "C"

        Case "Current Month +1"
            iCol = "N"
            nExtend = 4
        Case "Current Month +2"
            iCol = "O"
            nExtend = 3
        Case "Current Month +3"
            iCol = "P"
            nExtend = 2
        Case "Current Month +4"
            iCol = "Q"
    End Select

    actWarehouse = Me.warehousecombobox.ListIndex + 1

    With ws
        .Cells(irow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value


        For Each cel In .Cells(irow, iCol).Resize(, nExtend)
            cel.value = cel.value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Next cel
    End With

    With ws_warehouse(actWarehouse)
        'find part number
        l_row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        NewPart = True
        For r = 7 To l_row
            If Trim(.Range("A" & r)) = "" Then Exit For
            If LCase(.Range("A" & r)) = LCase(Me.PartTextBox.Text) Then
                irow = r
                Exit For
                NewPart = False
            End If
        Next r
        If NewPart Then irow = r

        .Cells(irow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value
        For Each cel In .Cells(irow, iCol).Resize(, nExtend)
            cel.value = cel.value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Next cel
    End With

    'clear the data
    Me.PartTextBox.value = ""
    Me.MonthComboBox.value = ""
    Me.AddTextBox.value = ""
    Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus
    Me.warehousecombobox.value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: UNION should help,`union(range("a1:a3"),range("c1:c3"))`, also If these are headers then use `Application.Worksheetfunction.Match("header val","headers",0)` as an offset from the 1st header.  So if headers are a1:J1, you'd offset from a1, the match-1, so for col C for example, the match would return 3, offset a1 3-2, =c1.  Take a look at `range("A1").offset(0,Application.WorksheetFunction.MATCH("Header",range("A1:J1"),0)).address`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I tried Union I have received a debug error _Global Failed.     nExtend = 1 'Set this as a default.
    Select Case MonthComboBox.value
        Case "Current Month"
           iCol = Union(Range("C"), Range("S"))
        Case "Current Month +1"
            iCol = "N"
            nExtend = 5
        Case "Current Month +2"
            iCol = "O"
            nExtend = 4
        Case "Current Month +3"
            iCol = "P"
            nExtend = 3
        Case "Current Month +4"
            iCol = "Q"
            nExtend = 2
    End Select

Comment: range("C:C") not single C, start range at C finish at C

Comment: If you paste the code where you are **using** these variables, we may be able to help you modify it appropriately.

Comment: @YowE3K I have included the full code

Comment: @Nathan_Sav full code included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you change your Select Case statement as follows:

```
Select Case MonthComboBox.value
    Case "Current Month"
        iCol = "C:C,S:S"
    Case "Current Month +1"
        iCol = "N:R"
    Case "Current Month +2"
        iCol = "O:R"
    Case "Current Month +3"
        iCol = "P:R"
    Case "Current Month +4"
        iCol = "Q:R"
End Select
```

(You won't need `nExtend` - it's built into the column specifications you set up in `iCol`.)

And then your `For Each cel` loops can both be changed to be

```
For Each cel In Intersect(.Rows(irow), .Range(iCol))
```

---

Your full revised code would be as follows:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()


    Dim irow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim iCol As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim value As Long
    Dim NewPart As Boolean
    Dim ws_warehouse(7) As Worksheet    '7 is total warehouse tab you have
    Dim cel As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Main")

    Set ws_warehouse(1) = Worksheets("Elkhart East")
    Set ws_warehouse(2) = Worksheets("Tennessee")
    Set ws_warehouse(3) = Worksheets("Alabama")
    Set ws_warehouse(4) = Worksheets("North Carolina")
    Set ws_warehouse(5) = Worksheets("Pennsylvania")
    Set ws_warehouse(6) = Worksheets("Texas")
    Set ws_warehouse(7) = Worksheets("West Coast")

    Set c = ws.Range("A7:A1048576").Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If c Is Nothing Then
    'find first empty row in database
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        irow = lastRow + 1
        NewPart = True
    Else
    'find row where the part is
        irow = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        NewPart = False
    End If

    'check for a part number
    If Trim(Me.PartTextBox.value) = "" Then
      Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Part Number"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.MonthComboBox.value) = "" Then
      Me.MonthComboBox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Month"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.AddTextbox.value) = "" Then
      Me.AddTextbox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Value To Add Or Substract"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case MonthComboBox.value
        Case "Current Month"
            iCol = "C:C,S:S"
        Case "Current Month +1"
            iCol = "N:R"
        Case "Current Month +2"
            iCol = "O:R"
        Case "Current Month +3"
            iCol = "P:R"
        Case "Current Month +4"
            iCol = "Q:R"
    End Select

    actWarehouse = Me.warehousecombobox.ListIndex + 1

    With ws
        .Cells(irow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value


        For Each cel In Intersect(.Rows(irow), .Range(iCol))
            cel.value = cel.value + CLng(Me.AddTextbox.value)
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Next cel
    End With

    With ws_warehouse(actWarehouse)
        'find part number
        l_row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        NewPart = True
        For r = 7 To l_row
            If Trim(.Range("A" & r)) = "" Then Exit For
            If LCase(.Range("A" & r)) = LCase(Me.PartTextBox.Text) Then
                irow = r
                Exit For
                NewPart = False
            End If
        Next r
        If NewPart Then irow = r

        .Cells(irow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value
        For Each cel In Intersect(.Rows(irow), .Range(iCol))
            cel.value = cel.value + CLng(Me.AddTextbox.value)
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Next cel
    End With

    'clear the data
    Me.PartTextBox.value = ""
    Me.MonthComboBox.value = ""
    Me.AddTextbox.value = ""
    Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus
    Me.warehousecombobox.value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```